# java put string array into another string array constructor

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm quite new to Java, and I'm not sure about is it possible to do something like below and how to do it with code.

```
    String[] a = {"a", "b", "c", ...}; //unknown amount of elements
    String[] b = new String[]{ //I want to put a's element in here assume I don't know what's the length of a };
```

Any idea of what I can put inside the braces after the constructor to initialize the string array b.

p.s. I'm not allowed to use string array a directly and must use constructor to declare string array b. I'm not allowed to use ArrayList.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying `b` should be a copy of `a`?

Comment: String[] a = {"a", "b", "c", ...};   this is a string array

Comment: and you are saying that you are not allowed to use string array

Comment: "and must use constructor to declare string array b" you don't use constructors to construct arrays.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most concise way would be:

```
String[] b = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length);
```

Comment: yay thats better than mine

Answer (score 1):

Use array copy to do the task.
Its prototype is:-

```
public static void arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)
```

> String[] a = {"a", "b", "c", ...}; //unknown amount of elements

```
String []b=new String[a.length];

System.arraycopy(a,0,b,0,a.length);
```